# My e.CommandArgument is returning "" Every Time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever I click one of the delete linkbuttons, the e.CommandArgument always retains the value of "". I was reading somewhere that you can't use <%# in Command Arguments but I have seen several examples were this has worked. Any suggestions?

In ASPX

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="dataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton CLASS="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnCommand="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ViewStateMode="Disabled">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[name], [data], convert(varchar, [date], 101) FROM [Announcements] ORDER BY [date] DESC">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

IN ASPX.CS

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Annoucnements WHERE id=@id";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", e.CommandArgument));

            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

As suggested by Royi Namir, changing EnableViewState to true fixed the problem.

Comment: What do you see in the HTML source of the button?

Comment: Just as an aside, you're already using an `SqlCommand` but not using parameters, you really should use parameters for Sql queries, especially where the data comes from the client. Look at Step 3 in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx it's old but it still applies =] (Yes I know it's unlikely that someone is going to change the code in your page but you never know, especially if it's a public-facing website.)

Comment: <a CLASS="DeleteButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$DataList1$ctl00$HeadLoginView$ctl01&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Delete</a>

Comment: Here is a similar post on the asp.net forums. It might provide a solution.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1303845.aspx/1

Comment: Your command argument is indeed empty, that function unescapes to this: `javascript:__doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$DataList1$ctl00$HeadLoginView$ctl01", "");`

Comment: Damn enter key! ^_^ Can you add a label or something to output the value of the `id` field on your data item into the page? This might help you to debug the issue a little more easily.

Comment: yea I already tested it Eval("id") returns the proper value its just not being set to the command argument for some reason :/

Comment: Yeah I'm sure I've done this before... Oh well we can always use the databinding events, I'll put an answer up for you in a sec =]

Comment: No problem, you can also use the shortcut `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.CommandArgument);` =]

Comment: change to EnableViewState="true"

Comment: @RoyiNamir Is it really that simple? Surely the control should know that it has ViewState disabled and adapt accordingly when it is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around for a little bit, I have found a few posts that say you can't use the `<%# ... %>` syntax inside server tags, which is clearly wrong as you are using it for the `Text` property and I'm sure I've done this exact same thing before. Anyway, you can use the `ItemDataBound` event on your `DataList`:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="dataLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="DeleteButton" runat="server" ID="lbDelete" OnCommand="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ViewStateMode="Disabled">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[name], [data], convert(varchar, [date], 101) FROM [Announcements] ORDER BY [date] DESC">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Notice I've added `ID="lbDelete"` to your `LinkButton` (and also changed `CLASS` to `CssClass` for you) which is needed to find the control in our code behind:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) // this is to ensure that we're looking in an item that will contain controls, and not the header or footer
    {
        LoginView headLoginView = (LoginView)e.Item.FindControl("HeadLoginView") // FindControl is not recursive so we need a reference to a control we can look in to find the button
        LinkButton lbDelete = (LinkButton)headLoginView.FindControl("lbDelete");

        if (lbDelete != null) // check for a null otherwise this code will fail if the user is not logged in, because the controls inside the LoggedInTemplate will not be rendered
        {
            lbDelete.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "id").ToString(); // set the CommandArgument on the button using DataBinder.Eval
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't like the e.Row(Does not contain a definition for Row)

Comment: Sorry, got mixed up between Repeaters and DataLists, just change Item to Row, I've edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Also, did you try Royi's suggestion about re-enabling the ViewState for that control? I'm interested to find out whether the CommandArgument is stored in ViewState....

Comment: Also it still seems to have to same problem. I added the code then removed my manual command argument. Was there anything else that was necessary?

Comment: No, that should have done it... Could you remove any bits you've added to do with ViewState from your code and try both methods again (this and the `<%# Eval("id") %>` method), that could be the issue, as weird and broken as that is =]

Comment: Crap.... setting the viewstate to true actually fixed it. I really appreciate your help Sean. I would add rep if I had high enough rep myself to do it :/

Comment: Lesson for today: you don't screw with ViewState, ViewState screws with you =D I'm glad I could help ^_^

Comment: Well I originally didn't mess with it but when I didn't set the viewstatemode at all it didn't work so I guess by default it was disabled or something.

Comment: ViewState is on by default for all controls, you have to explicitly turn it off =] it doesn't matter, we've all run into things like this where stuff just refuses to work and we have no idea why, it's all part of the fun ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the [DataKeyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datakeyfield.aspx) to uniquely identify your row in order to perform Delete operations.